# Can you use Firebase.Auth in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

I am exploring app development and doing Xamarin.Forms, and I want to use Firebase, so far looking at the Authentication thing. The problem is that I am not sure if possible and how to use it in Xamarin Forms, I've found some native documentation and something about forms but I couldn't really understand it or it was updated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Nuget package of xamarin:

Android:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth/

IOS:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Auth/

Here is a tutorial for Xamarin-forms:
https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/03/26/firebase-authentication-in-xamarin-forms/